# installing the latest R version (2.13.0) on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, updates, ubuntu-11.04, apt-get, r

I just upgraded my Ubuntu desktop 10.10 to 11.04. I everything works fine except when trying to update the current R 2.12.1 to R 2.13.0.

I followed the readme:

> http://cran.r-project.org/bin/Linux/Ubuntu/README

and added

```
deb http://cran.xl-mirror.nl/bin/Linux/Ubuntu natty/
deb-src http://cran.xl-mirror.nl/bin/Linux/Ubuntu natty/
deb http://nl.archive.Ubuntu.com/Ubuntu/ natty-backports restricted main multiverse universe
```

to my

> /etc/apt/sources.list

and also added

The Ubuntu archives on CRAN are signed with the key of "Michael Rutter
" with key ID E084DAB9. You can fetch
this key with

```
  gpg --keyserver keyserver.Ubuntu.com --recv-key E084DAB9
```

and then feed it to apt-key with

```
   gpg -a --export E084DAB9 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Which appears in the synaptic package manager (so I assume it worked).

but when running `sudo apt-get update` I  obtain an error saying that:

> Reading package lists... Error!
>
> E: Encountered a section with no
>   Package: header E: Problem with
>   MergeList
>   /var/lib/apt/lists/cran.xl-mirror.nl_bin_linux_ubuntu_natty_en
>   E: The package lists or status file
>   could not be parsed or opened. E:
>   _cache->open() failed, please report.

and

> An unresolvable problem occurred while
>   initializing the package information.
>
> Please report this bug against the
>   'update-manager' package and include
>   the following error message:
>
> 'E:Encountered a section with no
>   Package: header, E:Problem with
>   MergeList
>   /> var/lib/apt/lists/cran.xl-mirror.nl_bin_linux_ubuntu_natty_en,
>   E:The package lists or status file
>   could not be parsed or opened.'

how can I solve this? I am not an experienced Ubuntu user but have been using R on Mac and Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect the CRAN mirrors do not yet have a line for 'natty'.  Just make it

```
deb http://cran.xl-mirror.nl/bin/linux/ubuntu maverick/
```

for now and you should be fine.  This would have been a good question for the r-sig-debian list which is for questions regarding R on Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: No that is not working either - deb http://cran.xl-mirror.nl/bin/linux/ubuntu maverick/ - gives me the same error.

Comment: Did you try a different CRAN mirror?

Comment: no. I tried the deb http://cran.xl-mirror.nl/bin/linux/ubuntu maverick/  which I am always using. I can try another one.

Comment: solved - I ended up using a different mirror:deb http://cran-mirror.cs.uu.nl/bin/linux/ubuntu natty/ which worked. thanks.

Comment: In which case maverick also worked?

Comment: deb http://cran.xl-mirror.nl/bin/linux/ubuntu maverick/ did not work so I started with deb cran-mirror.cs.uu.nl/bin/linux/ubuntu natty/ which worked.